# DensityPlot with one log axis

Tags: plotting

Is there any way of generating a density plot (or something similar) with one of its axes on a log scale? Essentially I'm trying to combine a `LogLinearPlot` and a normal `Plot` on two different variables to create the associated density plot.

If this can't be done directly, what would be the best work-around?

Comment: If you add a small self-contained example you will get more/better answers.

Comment: I can't think of an easier workaround than: `DensityPlot[f[x,y], {x, Xmin, Xmax}, {y, Ymin, Ymax}]` to `DensityPlot[f[x, E^y],{x, Xmin, Xmax}, {y, Log@Ymin, Log@Ymax}]`. Adding ticks along `y` might take you some time but it shouldn't be hard (I've assumed that's the direction you want to log plot)

Comment: I think `ScalingFunctions` works with `DensityPlot`... That might help.

Comment: @cormullion Could you give an example? I can only get it working for the function value but not the axis. (Something like `DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]`)

Comment: @silvia no I can't (:-() but I thought there might be those who were clever enough to make it happen...

Comment: @cormullion Maybe an option which wraps @ gpap's method into `DensityPlot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the input in the comments; here's what I eventually came up with (including tick placement):

```
fSpace[min_, max_, steps_, f_: Identity] := 
 InverseFunction[f] /@ 
  Range[f@min, f@max, (f@max - f@min)/(steps - 1)]
GetMajorTicks[min_, max_, count_, f_: Identity] := 
  fSpace[min, max, count, f];
GetMinorTicks[min_, max_, majorCount_, minorCount_, f_: Identity] := 
  Flatten[Table[
    Drop[Drop[
      fSpace[x, 
       x ((f@max - f@min)/(majorCount - 1) // InverseFunction[f]), 
       minorCount + 2], 1], -1], {x, 
     Drop[GetMajorTicks[min, max, majorCount, f], -1]}]];

xMin = 1/4;
xMax = 4;
xMajorTicks = 5;
xMinorTicks = 3;
f = Log;
ContourPlot[
 Sin[2 \[Pi] y] InverseFunction[f]@x, {x, f@xMin, f@xMax}, {y, -1, 1},
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    None}, {({f@#, # // N} & /@ 
       GetMajorTicks[xMin, xMax, xMajorTicks, f])~
     Join~({f@#, Null, {0.005, 0}} & /@ 
       GetMinorTicks[xMin, xMax, xMajorTicks, xMinorTicks, f]), 
    None}}]
```

> [image: The plot]

If this can be cleaned up or improved in any way, I'd love to hear!