# DensityPlot with logarithmic xy-axes and logarithmic color scale

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I would like to do a DensityPlot with logarithmic xy-axes and logarithmic color scale for the function

\begin{align}
 S(\epsilon_{v},\epsilon_{\phi}) = \frac{\pi}{\epsilon_{v}} \frac{\sinh \left(\frac{2 \pi \epsilon_{v}}{\pi^{2} \epsilon_{\phi}/6} \right)}{\cosh \left(\frac{2 \pi \epsilon_{v}}{\pi^{2} \epsilon_{\phi}/6} \right) - \cos \left(2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi^{2} \epsilon_{\phi}/6} - \left( \frac{\epsilon_{v}}{\pi^{2} \epsilon_{\phi}/6} \right)^{2}} \right)}\\
~\\
\epsilon_{v} \to x , \epsilon_{\phi} \to y~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\end{align}

[Background: Considering velocity dependent Dark Matter interaction this function (Sommerfeld enhancement) arises when solving the corresponding Schrödinger equation with a Hulthén potential]

While searching for a solution I found these two posts:

1) [Logarithmic scale in a DensityPlot and its legend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36830/logarithmic-scale-in-a-densityplot-and-its-legend)

2) [DensityPlot with one log axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18866/densityplot-with-one-log-axis)

But I am searching in some sense a combination of these two ideas.

Alas I started using Mathematica only a few weeks ago and I am not familiar with all its features.
Hence, I came to no satisfactorily result yet and would be very happy if anyone can help.

Here the Matematica code which I in principle took from 1):

```
f[x_, y_] := 
  Pi/x * Sinh[
     12*x/(Pi*y)]/(Cosh[12*x/(Pi*y)] - 
      Cos[2*Pi*Sqrt[ 6/(Pi*Pi*y) - (6*x/(Pi*Pi*y))^2]]);



plotter[min_, max_, NumberOfTicks_] := 
 DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 10^(-6), 10^(0)}, {y, 1/(10^4), 1/(10^3)}, 
  PlotPoints -> 10, PlotRange -> Full, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
      LogarithmicScaling[#, min, max]] &), 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{ColorData["Rainbow"], {0, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 340, 
    Ticks -> ({LogarithmicScaling[#, min, max], 
         ScientificForm[#, 2]} & /@ (min (max/min)^
          Range[0, 1, 1/NumberOfTicks]))]]
plotter[1, 10^(6), 6]
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could at least propose a form of your function in *Mathematica* code, rather than as a LaTex expression. Furthermore, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102132)?

Comment: @J.M. : Not yet, thank you! But this is in principle just an extension of 1). I am missing the logarithmic xy axes, since it seems to me that just the color scale has an arbitrary non-linear form.

Comment: I'd define `g[x_,y_] := f[10^x, 10^y]` and plot `g` with the range `{x, -6, 0}, {y, -4, -3}`.

Answer (score 4):

wxffles suggestion to use a helper function to do the coordinate transformation seems quite effective:

```
f[x_, y_] := Pi/x*Sinh[12*x/(Pi*y)]/(Cosh[12*x/(Pi*y)] - 
      Cos[2*Pi*Sqrt[6/(Pi*Pi*y) - (6*x/(Pi*Pi*y))^2]]);

helper[x_, y_] = f[10^x, 10^y];

LogarithmicScaling[x_, min_, max_] := Log[x/min]/Log[max/min]
plotter[min_, max_, NumberOfTicks_] := DensityPlot[

  (* Modification to use the helper function *)
  helper[x, y],
  {x, -6, 0}, {y, -4, -3},
  (* end modification *)

  PlotRange -> Full,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
      LogarithmicScaling[#, min, max]] &),

  PlotLegends ->
   BarLegend[{ColorData["Rainbow"], {0, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 340, 
    Ticks -> ({LogarithmicScaling[#, min, max], 
         ScientificForm[#, 2]} & /@ (min (max/min)^
          Range[0, 1, 1/NumberOfTicks]))]
  ]
```

With these in place:

```
plotter[1, 1*^6, 6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

This uses the `CustomTicks` package available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kmisiunas/mathematica-customticks/master/CustomTicks.m), and the `nonLinearDensityPlot` function defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102133/9490).  See below for a version that does not use these add-ons

```
loglogDensityPlot[func_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, 
    plotopts : OptionsPattern[{DensityPlot, nonLinearDensityPlot}]] :=
  nonLinearDensityPlot[
  func /. {x -> Exp[x], y -> Exp[y]}, {x, Log@xmin, Log@xmax}, {y, 
   Log@ymin, Log@ymax},
  FrameTicks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}],
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]},
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}},
  Evaluated -> True,
  plotopts]
```

By default this function uses an `ArcSinh` scaling function, that doesn't look great for your data

```
loglogDensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 1/1000000, 1}, {y, 1/10000, 1/1000}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To change this, you need to provide a scaling function that maps the values your function can take to the range `{0,1}`.  The arguments of the scaling function are `{value, scalefactor, maxval, minval}`.  So to get linear scaling we use `((#1 - #4)/(#3 - #4) &)`.  For the log scaling we use

```
loglogDensityPlot[
 f[x, y], {x, 10^(-6), 10^(0)}, {y, 1/(10^4), 1/(10^3)}, 
 "ScalingFunction" -> (Log[#1/#4]/Log[#3/#4] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is a version that doesn't use external packages, but I can't get a nice legend out of it.  It is similar to MarcoB's answer,

```
loglogDensityPlot[func_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 DensityPlot[Log@(func /. {x -> Exp[x], y -> Exp[y]}),
  {x, Log@xmin, Log@xmax}, {y, Log@ymin, Log@ymax},
  FrameTicks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}],
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]},
  opts, PlotRange -> All,
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}},
  Evaluated -> True
  ]

loglogDensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 1/1000000, 1}, {y, 1/10000, 1/1000}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]