# How to rescale the axis on a graph to make it more readable

Tags: graphics, logarithmic-scale, scaling

I am currently trying to plot an implicit function of the form $f(x,y) = 0$ in mathematica.

The example I am using is $f(x,y) = y^4 - 730 y^2 + x^4 + 3y^2 x^2 - 675 x^2 + 729$

However the function has a small circle type shape at the origin and a another large circular shape around the origin:

[image]

This was plotted using the mathematica command:

```
ContourPlot[729 + x^4 + y^4 + 3 x^2 (-225 + y^2) == 730 y^2,
 {x, -32, 32}, {y, -34, 34}]
```

Question: is there some way to make the plot so that the smaller circle becomes more visible?

Comment: This seems related: [(18866)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18866/121)

Answer (score 4):

Revising this answer I propose extracting contours from `ContourPlot`, converting to polar, scaling magnitude, then converting back and plotting.  I will use code from [ListLogLinearPlot for the whole real numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78524/121):

```
logify[_][x_ /; x == 0] := 0
logify[off_][x_] := Sign[x] Max[0, (off + Re@Log@x)/off]

inverse[off_][x_] := Sign[x] Exp[(Abs[x] - 1) off]

logscale[n_] := {logify[n], inverse[n]}
```

And an auxiliary function:

```
logTheta[m_][pts_] :=
  FromPolarCoordinates /@ 
    MapAt[logify[m], ToPolarCoordinates /@ pts, {All, 1}];
```

Now:

```
cp = ContourPlot[
   729 + x^4 + y^4 + 3 x^2 (-225 + y^2) == 730 y^2, {x, -32, 32}, {y, -34, 34}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 3];

pts = Cases[Normal @ cp, Line[x_] :> x, -3];

ListLinePlot[logTheta[2] /@ pts
  , Ticks -> Charting`ScaledTicks @ logscale[2]
  , AspectRatio -> 1
]
```

[image]

An additional example to better illustrate variable "zoom" in the scaling:

```
cp2 = ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[x^2 + y^2 == # & /@ (3^Range[-3, 5])], {x, -16, 16}, {y, -16, 16}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50]

pts2 = Cases[Normal@cp2, Line[x_] :> x, -3];

ListLinePlot[logTheta[#] /@ pts2
 , Ticks -> Charting`ScaledTicks @ logscale[#]
 , AspectRatio -> 1
] & /@ {2, 3, 4}
```

[image]

[image]

Beware: if the "zoom" is not enough you'll create singularities in the polar/Cartesian conversion and get errors instead of a plot:

```
logTheta[1] /@ pts2;
```

> FromPolarCoordinates::bdpt: Evaluation point {0,1.92728} is not a
>   valid set of polar or hyperspherical coordinates. >>

I expect this will be a problem if you have contours that cross the origin, but I will have to come back to that later.

### Controlling tick marks

Here is a way to "manually" generate a specification for [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) or [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html).

```
cp = ContourPlot[
   729 + x^4 + y^4 + 3 x^2 (-225 + y^2) == 730 y^2, {x, -32, 32}, {y, -34, 34}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 3];

pts = Cases[Normal@cp, Line[x_] :> x, -3];

log = logTheta[2] /@ pts;

ticks = {#, inverse[2][#]} & /@ FindDivisions[#, 11] & /@ CoordinateBounds[log];

ListLinePlot[log, Ticks -> ticks, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

And for the additional example:

```
cp2 = ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[x^2 + y^2 == # & /@ (3^Range[-3, 5])], {x, -16, 16}, {y, -16, 16}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50]

pts2 = Cases[Normal@cp2, Line[x_] :> x, -3];

Table[
  log = logTheta[b] /@ pts2;
  ticks = {#, inverse[b][#]} & /@ FindDivisions[#, 11] & /@ CoordinateBounds[log];
  ListLinePlot[log, Ticks -> ticks, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200],
  {b, {2, 3, 4}}
] // Row
```

[image]

Comment: How would you add ticks back to these images?

Comment: For some reason when I copy this code, the ticks are not showing up on the image, do you perhaps know why this is?

Comment: @GrEg You're using the code with ``Ticks -> Charting`ScaledTicks @ logscale[2]`` right?  I guess it's a version issue; which version of *Mathematica* are you using?  I'll add code for "manual" tick generation later if I have time.

Comment: I am using the online version of mathematica from wolfram alpha. Yeah I am using that code. Thanks I would appreciate it!

Comment: I think the version is 11.1.1

Comment: @GrEg I added examples with generated tick marks.  If you don't like the $e^x$ labels you can `Round` them, but it's harder to be both clean and accurate that way.  But try e.g. ``ticks = {#, inverse[2][#] ~Round~ 0.02} & /@ FindDivisions[#, 11] & /@ CoordinateBounds[log];`` to see how that looks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
ContourPlot[
 729 + x^4 + y^4 + 3 x^2 (-225 + y^2) - 730 y^2,
 {x, -32, 32}, {y, -34, 34},
 Contours -> {{0}},
 ContourShading -> {White, Orange}]
```

[image]

You can magnify the center circle by decreasing the `PlotRange`

```
r = 5;

ContourPlot[
 729 + x^4 + y^4 + 3 x^2 (-225 + y^2) - 730 y^2,
 {x, -32, 32}, {y, -34, 34},
 Contours -> {{0}},
 ContourShading -> {White, Orange},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was thinking something more along the lines of changing the scales to a logarithmic scale, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Is there no way of setting an 'axis scale'?

Comment: Not with `ContourPlot` or `RegionPlot`

Answer (score 1):

You could rescale your variables with something like:

```
lhs[x_, y_] := 729 + x^4 + y^4 + 3 x^2 (-225 + y^2)
rhs[y_] := 730 y^2
ticks = {#, #} &@{Table[{Sign[i] Sqrt[Abs[i]], i}, {i, -30, 30, 10}], Automatic};
```

Then

```
ContourPlot[lhs[Sign[x] x^2, Sign[y] y^2] == rhs[Sign[y] y^2], 
  {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, FrameTicks -> ticks]
```

gives

[image]